# Inspection info: Verifies @ConfigurationProperties setup. New in 2018.3 IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

I get the following hint in the latest IntelliJ Idea:

```
Not registered via @EnableConfigurationProperties or marked as Spring 
component less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: Verifies @ConfigurationProperties setup. New in 2018.3
```

With the following configuration:

```
@Configuration 
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp.reference")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyAppFactoryConfiguration.class)
@Profile("dev")
public class MyAppLibraryConfigDev {
```

It goes away if I add @Component, but isn't @Configuration already an @Component?

Not sure what it means, anyone?

Comment: Please report an issue on YouTrack attaching sample project example: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: @powder366 did you create the bug? was this bug fixed? I am still getting the error on v2018.3

Comment: No I did not create a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was [reported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-204153) and declined as a bug. Because it is semantically incorrect (or less desirable) to declare a dumb properties PoJo (or Bean) as a `@Configuration` instead of a simpler `@Component`. Because a `@configuration` is a special kind of `@component` which can produce Beans itself.